# Google Sheets Time-Driven trigger didn't execute

Tags: google-apps-script

I've setup a Google Script that is time-driven, to be executed daily. On most days, it executes, but on some, it just doesn't execute at all.
As you can see in the image below, the Import CSV just didn't run on the 24th or 25th.

[image: As you can see, it didn't execute on 25 or 26]

Do you have any idea why this could be happening?
I'll add the code on the bottom so you can take a look and help me understand. But please note that the code works when executed, but, it seems not to execute.
At times, when it executes, it says that it has exceeded the quota but works anyway.

Basically all the script does is go over to the e-mail and grab the required csv file from the e-mail, which it then appends over on the Google Sheet.

```js
function LaredouteDownloadIntake() {

  var sheetId="1HMlwxNS99p75IdRHXo1QoeWDWEz0gbTnqNufCfmqyzc";

  var threads = GmailApp.search("from:no-reply@omniture.com subject:Classeur Excel (labelium_it.xlsx) in:inbox newer_than:1d filename:.csv");
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[3];

  attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();
  Logger.log(attachment.getContentType());

  if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {

    console.log("Funcion checking if csv exists");
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheetByName('LaredouteITAdobe');
    var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");

    var column = sheet.getRange('A:A');
    var values = column.getValues(); // get all data in one call
    var ct = 0;
    while ( values[ct][0] != "" ) {
      ct++;
    }

    sheet.getRange(ct, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

    var threads = GmailApp.search("from:no-reply@omniture.com subject:Classeur Excel (labelium_com.xlsx) in:inbox newer_than:1d filename:.csv");
    var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];
    var attachment = message.getAttachments()[3];

    attachment.setContentTypeFromExtension();

    Logger.log(attachment.getContentType());

    if (attachment.getContentType() === "text/csv") {
      console.log("Funcion checking if csv exists");
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheetId).getSheetByName('LaredouteCOMAdobe');
      var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(attachment.getDataAsString(), ",");      
      var column = sheet.getRange('A:A');
      var values = column.getValues(); // get all data in one call
      var ct = 0;
      while ( values[ct][0] != "" ) {
        ct++;
      }

      sheet.getRange(ct, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trigger settings? Also, what is the log of the execution logs for the 25th and 26th?

Comment: Trigger settings are: Choose which function to run: LaredouteDownloadIntake,
Which runs at deployment: head,
Select event source: Time-driven,
Select type of time based trigger: Day Timer,
Select time of day: 5am to 6am

Comment: @RafaGuillermo There is no log of execution for 25th or 26th. Only 21, 22, 23, 24 and 27. There's an image on my post which displays what I see in the platform. Thus, the error rate of this script is 0%, since it supposedly never failed. Since the trigger didn't run on 25th or 26th, the script error rate is still 0%. Could it being a weekend have anything to do with it?

Comment: It being the weekend shouldn't be a factor in this. If this on a day timer or a 24 hours timer? Also, do you have a G Suite account or are you running this with a @gmail account?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a G Suite account, but it is a company e-mail, with our domain on it and not @gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### This appears to be a bug!

I have taken the liberty of reporting this on Google's Issue Tracker for you, detailing the behaviour:

- [Time-Driven Triggers not executing and not showing errors in the Execution Log](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/148509930)

You can hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the page which lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.